# Unknown CRON job sending email after boot

Tags: server, cron, email

I have a question about mysterious CRON job which runs aftery every boot and sends me following email:

[picture (at least 10 reps needed)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1C8fT.png)

System: Ubuntu 20.04

I can't locate the cron job that does that using `crontab -l` for all users. It's also not in /etc/crontab:

```
# Unlike any other crontab you don't have to run the `crontab'
# command to install the new version when you edit this file
# and files in /etc/cron.d. These files also have username fields,
# that none of the other crontabs do.

SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

# Example of job definition:
# .---------------- minute (0 - 59)
# |  .------------- hour (0 - 23)
# |  |  .---------- day of month (1 - 31)
# |  |  |  .------- month (1 - 12) OR jan,feb,mar,apr ...
# |  |  |  |  .---- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0 or 7) OR sun,mon,tue,wed,thu,fri,sat
# |  |  |  |  |
# *  *  *  *  * user-name command to be executed
17 *    * * *   root    cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly
25 6    * * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )
47 6    * * 7   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly )
52 6    1 * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.monthly )
```

I understand that it will not appear in any of hourly/weekly/monthly jobs since it only appears after reboot.

I'll be grateful for any ideas on how I can locate that CRON job and what does it do.

Comment: any files in the /etc/cron* directories ?

Comment: yes, thank you, actually I found it in `/etc/cron.d/sysctl`, but now I wonder how it got there and what is the purpose of it (can I delete it?). Isn't the job pointless?